# how to pass generic list parameter into a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms

I am getting phone contacts into a list<> and saving it in a database.
Below is my code.

This is my method to get the contacts-List

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    try {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        TextView txtcount = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        List<PersonContact> a1 = GetPhoneContacts();

        Phone gp = new Phone();

        gp.insertContact(a1);
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        alert(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Via the following method I am trying to store contacts in database

```
[WebMethod]
public string insertContact<T>(List<PersonContact> a) {
    OpenConnection();
    if (a.Count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) {
            string str = "insert into phone_contact (FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber)values('" + a[i].FirstName + "','" + a[i].LastName + "','" + a[i].PhoneNumber + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return "1";
    } else {
        return "1";
    }
}

public class PersonContact {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting an error while passing parameter

```
 gp.insertContact(a1);
```

Comment: Always include the exact error message, not just a mention about one

Answer (score 7):

Your method is generic, as it introduces a new type parameter `T`. That's what the `<T>` at the end of the method name means.

However, you don't *use* `T` anywhere - so just make it a non-generic method:

```
public string InsertContact(List<PersonContact> a)
```

At the same time, I would *very strongly* urge you to change the way you're doing database access: it's currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, you should use parameterized SQL: have one parameter for each of `FirstName`, `LastName` and `PhoneNumber`.

You're also returning `"1"` regardless of the input. Your method could be written more simply as:

```
// Consider renaming to InsertContacts, as it's not just dealing with a single
// contact
public string InsertContact(List<PersonContact> contacts)
{
    // You should almost certainly use a using statement here, to
    // dispose of the connection afterwards
    OpenConnection();
    foreach (var contact in contacts)
    {
        // Insert the contact. Use a using statement for the SqlCommand too.
    }
    return "1";
}
```

That's assuming you need the value returned at all - if you're always returning the same value, why not just make it a `void` method?

Comment: You have valid points but I do not think you have answered the question. Instead you did a code review. Sami is correct in asking for the error.

Comment: I would personally also do a null-check on the argument.

Comment: @Aldert: I believe I *have* answered the question, because I strongly expect that that error would be that the type argument can't be inferred. I agree that the question would be better if it included the error message, but I'm pretty confident about what the problem is, and that my answer fixes it.